# jQuery Mask - Conditional

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am very new to jQuery and am using the masked input plugin version 1.3 to create a mask for phone numbers.

I was able to set it up and have the mask work correctly, however I would like to apply a condition for the mask based upon a select box change.

When the page loads a select box with the id of #Country is loaded an is set to have 'United States' selected by default.  What I am trying to create is if they change the country selector to something other than the United States choice, remove the mask.

This is my first attempt!

```
    $('#Country').change(function(){
    var cty = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value');
    if(cty=='United States'){
        // us masking
        $('#phone').unmask().mask("(999) 999-9999");

    } else {
        // just numbers for international
        $('#phone').unmask().mask("9999999999999999");

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to get the answere squared away and displayed correctly (asker comment)

```
$('#phone').mask('(999) 999-9999');  
$('#Country').change(function(){ 
  var cty = $(this).val(); 
  if(cty=='United States'){ 
    // us masking 
    $('#phone').unmask().mask("(999) 999-9999"); 
  } else { 
    // just numbers for international 
    $('#phone').unmask().mask("9999999999999999"); 
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with you code.
Rather than 
var cty = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value');
try
var cty = $(this).val()

and try to debug your code by adding some
console.log("mask us")
console.log("mask non-us")
inside your if/else statements.
If your console.log() show the expected values, then the problem reside in your plugin, so try to contact its author directly.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I got it to work with the following.  Because US is selected on page load it needed it to be like this (I think)  . I was only able to get the mask if I clicked in the select box: 

    $('#phone').mask('(999) 999-9999');  
$('#Country').change(function(){
        var cty = $(this).val();
        if(cty=='United States'){
            // us masking
            $('#phone').unmask().mask("(999) 999-9999");
            
        } else {
            // just numbers for international
            $('#phone').unmask().mask("9999999999999999");
           
        }
    });